# How to show 2nd, 3rd etc. highest values in a table using SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I'm looking for a way to add some more columns to a query to show values other than just the top one.

It is essentially show show quantities on purchase orders in date order with the newest first.

this is what we have so far which give is the more recent value.

```
(select top 1 
   s0.ShipDate 
from 
   por1 s0 
where 
   s0.itemcode=t0.itemcode 
   and s0.OpenQty<>0 
order by 
   s0.shipdate)as 'Delivery Date',
(select top 1 
   s0.OpenQty 
from 
   por1 s0 
where 
   s0.itemcode=t0.itemcode 
   and s0.OpenQty<>0 
order by 
   s0.shipdate asc)as 'Open Qty'
```

How can I add 3 more columns to show the 2nd, 3rd and 4th highest value please?

Comment: How about some sample data and expected output...?

Comment: Sub-SKU Status Active Stock Sell_Price Sales Tax Definition Sale_Item NameTxtCost InitTextCost NumTextCost Picture Old Price Fabric Weight New Product Delivery Date Open Qty Delivery Date Open Qty  Delivery Date Open Qty Delivery Date Open Qty
CCB004PU-M N YES 12 16 O1  0 0 0  0   NO 31.07.17 10       
DMU001BLK/RE-08 N YES 6 24.75 O1  0 0 0  0   NO 31.12.17 10       
DMU001BLK/RE-10 N YES 7 24.75 O1  0 0 0  0   NO 31.12.17 15

Comment: The output currently shows the closest purchase date and quantity in the last 2 columns.   I would like to show another 6 columns for the 2nd, 3rd and 4th closest purchase orders with the ship date and quantity.  thanks

Comment: Please post the sample data and expected output in the original question